# Ajax call to a servlet from JSP page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make a AJAX call from JSP Page, But I am unable to render the returned response to the textarea. Ajax call is giving the correct response, I am able to log on Console but unable to append to textarea

Below is the code:

Index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image:
        url('https://cdn.crunchify.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Crunchify.bg_.300.png');
}
</style>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Initialization</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea rows="6" cols="25" id="request"></textarea>
        <button id="Submit">Submit</button>
        <textarea rows="6" cols="25" id="response"></textarea>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Submit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                request : $('#request').val()
            },
            url : 'Initialization',
            success : function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#response').text(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: try with $('#response').val(result);

Comment: try `.html(result)`

Comment: I tried val @GurkanYesilyurt and html  both are not working, I think it appends the data but immediately it disappears, Can you think of why this happens

Comment: add  type='button' your button and try again please. maybe it reload page

Comment: Cheers Mate!! @GurkanYesilyurt  Got it, Can you explain me why this happened because of type button

Comment: I think if type is empty, then browser set it automatically submit

Comment: Did you try with text box rather than a text area?

Comment: @YashwanthPotu If you accept my answer, I would be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to cancel the default action of the form by using:
`evt.preventDefault();`
And use val() to set the response.

```
$(document).ready(function(evt) {
    console.log("submit")

    $('#Submit').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                name : $('#request').val()
            },

            url : 'Initialization',
            success : function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                $('#response').val(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify explicitly your button type `type='button'` and try again, please. Otherwise, this might cause a page reload.